# Report on duty or Report for duty?

Tags: prepositions

> I have to report on duty on 22th December 2014.

It should be **on** or **for**?

If that day I have attend, I have report to someone that I have on duty that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to report for duty on 22 DEC.

Means you have Duty scheduled for 22 DEC and have to show up.

> I have to report on duty.

Implies that you have to make a report of some kind while on duty.  "I have to report the number of visitors while on duty tomorrow."

Answer (score 3):

You "report FOR duty". Once you have done so, you may be "ON duty". For example, "I have to report for duty on 22 December. Then I will be on duty until 15 March."

Note that in "report for duty", we often, as in your example, give a date, and that date is preceded by "on". So if it wasn't necessary in context to say "for duty", you could say "report on", as in, "I have to report on 22 December."

"Report on" can also mean that you are presenting information about some subject. Like, "At the committee meeting, Jack reported on new product development and Sally reported on the results of the recent advertising campaign."

The meanings and definitions of prepositions in English can be muddled. I think in many cases you just have to memorize which prepositions are used in which context. In this case, I suppose you could say that "on" normally means either "sitting atop", as in, "The book is ON the table", or "about", as in, "This is a book on ancient history." "For" means "in favor of", as in, "Senator Jones is for the new tax bill", or "for the purpose or benefit of", as in, "I work for money" or "I quit smoking for my wife."

In this case, we say "reporting for duty" in the sense that the reason why you are reporting is to perform your duty, so it sort of makes sense.

Comment: 'For' can also carry the meaning of 'in exchange', giving rise to the old joke, "I got a new set of golf clubs for my wife." "Did you? Good swap" ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin True. And "I am working for my wife" could mean "The reason why I am working is because I need to support my wife financially", or it could mean, "My wife is my employer." Prepositions tend to have many possible meanings. My intent wasn't to list all the possible meanings, but the most common ones.

Comment: Sure, it was just "I quit smoking for my wife" that prompted me, I wondered if she perhaps didn't want to quit herself ;)